# Make a plot from data

Tags: plotting, data, list-manipulation

I have two variables $x$ and $y$ satisfying, say, $y^2 + x < 1$, such that $0 \le x < 1$ and $0\le y<1$. I want to plot all the points satisfying the inequality $y^2 + x < 1$ and also show the parabolic curve $y^2 + x = 1$ in the same plot. As a try, I started with table

`tb = Table[x^2 + y < 1, {x, 0, 1, 0.2}, {y, 0, 1, 0.2}]`,

but it did not lead to anything. Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 4):

```
RegionPlot[y^2 + x <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

You may use `ContourPlot` to draw just the curve:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 + x == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```